When do enemies get added to to the Piklopedia?
What are the conditions to unlock an enemy's Piklopedia entry in Pikmin 2? Do entries show up if an enemy is encountered for the first time? Do they have to be defeated first? Does a sample of the enemy need to be carried by the Pikmin back to the ship?

According to Gamefaqs:

The Piklopedia updates after you either:

defeat an enemy and bring it to the ship
defeat an enemy that CANNOT be picked up
walk through a plant
you use certain plants


